# Ruby gmail gem and storing credentials

Tags: ruby, security, email, gmail, nokogiri

I'm writing a very small program that I'd like to run on my RPI in a cron job. Every hour I want to check the status of a webpage. If the status meets a certain criteria I want it to email me.

In the past I have successfully used the gmail gem however I have always had to provide my credentials. I am nervous about storing my gmail credentials on file. Does anyone know how to accomplish this task more securely?

The end goal is I want an email in my inbox that tells me that a gate status has changed on the website I'm monitoring.

Here is what I have so far

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'


def check_gates
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.summitatsnoqualmie.com/Mountains/Grooming-Report'))
    gates = {}

    table_rows = doc.xpath('//tr')

    sections = []

    sections.push({:gate => "Elevator", :data => table_rows.select { |tr| tr.inspect.include? "Lower Traverse" }.first})
    sections.push({:gate => "Nash", :data => table_rows.select { |tr| tr.inspect.include? "Upper Traverse" }.first})

    sections.each do |section|
        status_text =  section[:data].element_children.select { |child| child.inspect.include? "grooming_open_status" }.first.inspect
        match = status_text.match(/background-position:\ (\d+)px\ (.\d)+px/)

        gate_down = false

        unless match.nil?
            gate_down = match[1].to_i == 0 and match[2].to_i == 0
        end

        gates[section[:gate]] = gate_down ? "CLOSED" : "OPEN"

    end

    gates
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Generate an application-specific password for your Google account](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1173270?hl=en), and store that password on the server.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try this but still plan to. Hopefully later today or tomorrow.